# Add onCreateOptionsMenu items from a web service

Tags: android, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have to dynamically change the `onCreateOptionsMenu` items. I am fetching the items from a web service. But the problem is that the service is called in `onCreate()` and in an `AsyncTask` class so before the data from the service arrives `onCreateOptionsMenu` gets called and returns `NullPointerException`.

Here's how I am calling the function:

```
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    item = menu.findItem(R.id.CurrentUser);
    UserName = con.getResources().getString(R.string.WelcomeUser) + " "
            + UserName + "!";
    item.setTitle(UserName);

    if (IsCorporateAccount) {
        menu.getItem(6).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        menu.getItem(6).setVisible(false);
    }

    objGetBalanceDetails.CreateMenu(menu);

    // Menu menu1 = null;
    // menu1.findItem(R.id.Home).setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: is my answer helpful?? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can grab menu in `onCreateOptions` menu

```
private Menu mMenu;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    }
```

and after making changes in your menu i.e adding or removing items , you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` (support for api > 11) to update your menu.

Comment: the function that filling the optionsmenu is another java file and is fetching data from a web service.The problem is the delay.. if i toggle a break point and produce a delay then the whole thing is working fine..

Comment: you can create something like delegate that will notify you when asyntask finishd. so after then immedeiately create your menu.